# Ordering Object and Selecting based on custom priority

Tags: c#, linq, sql-order-by

I have a custom priority array.

```
int[] priorities = { 866, 663, 855, 853, 854};
```

And I have this code to currently to sort through my list and pick the first based on the criteria.

```
            var target = (from people in GetNearbyPeopleList()
                          where people.DistanceToTravel > 0 && people.ReachedDestination == false
                          orderby //not sure what to do here
                          select people).FirstOrDefault();
```

So I want to order by my custom priorities. Where people.currentlocation is ordered by my priorities array.

Do I do - ?

```
orderby priorities.Contains(people.currentlocation)
```

That's all I can think of, but it does not properly order by the order of my custom priorities. I want it to follow this order exactly:

```
int[] priorities = { 866, 663, 855, 853, 854};
```

So if location is 866, pick that one. I only want to select one and I want to select the first based on that priority list. If currentlocation == 866 does not exist, then pick 663 and so and so on.

Comment: If the result of NearyPeopleList AsEnumerable or AsQueryable? In other words, is this result a query to be performed by a database, or a sequence of items in local memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your values are fixed at compile-time... avoid the array and write:

```
orderby
  people.currentLocation == 866 ? 1 :
  people.currentLocation == 663 ? 2 :
  people.currentLocation == 855 ? 3 :
  people.currentLocation == 853 ? 4 :
  people.currentLocation == 854 ? 5 :
  6
```

If your values change at run-time, but the number of values has some fixed maximum, then write:

```
Person FindPriorityPerson(IQueryable<Person> query,
  int p1 = 0, int p2 = 0, int p3 = 0, int p4 = 0,
  int p5 = 0, int p6 = 0, int p7 = 0, int p8 = 0)
{
  return query.OrderBy(person =>
    person.currentLocation == p1 ? 1 :
    person.currentLocation == p2 ? 2 :
    person.currentLocation == p3 ? 3 :
    person.currentLocation == p4 ? 4 :
    person.currentLocation == p5 ? 5 :
    person.currentLocation == p6 ? 6 :
    person.currentLocation == p7 ? 7 :
    person.currentLocation == p8 ? 8 :
    9).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do it.   This gives you sorting based on array order.

Had to add logic so -1 (not found) is at the end

```
orderby Array.IndexOf(priorities, people.currentLocation) == -1 ? Integer.MaxValue : Array.IndexOf(priorities, people.currentLocation);
```

Comment: I get the error - No overload for method of 'IndexOf' takes 1 arguements.

Comment: changed it to array.indexof

Comment: System.NotSupportedException: Method 'Int32 IndexOf[Int32](Int32[], Int32)' has no supported translation to SQL

Answer (score 0):

<s>This can not be done this way.</s>* Linq can not work with your own array the way you need. But there are several other ways to do that I can think of

- Redesign you application so you have the priorities in **table on the server**.
- Use table valued parameter (**TVP**). That is the right way to send your array to the server to be used in the query, it scales to thousands of items without issue. It needs server that supports that (like Microsoft SQL server) and the query has to be done outside the linq. Linq does not support that.
- Use **`Contains`** and query all items, pick the first on the client. `Contains` can use your own array, however be aware it converts it into parameters, one value means one parameter. Do not use it if you have too many items (>100) in the array or the query would be slow and would crash for more than approx 2000 items (depends on server type).
- **Loop the array** and query one item a time. You can combine it with Contains and query 10 items a time for example to speed it up.

*Amy B found a way, my bad. But beware of the limits. It uses not one, but two parameters per every value, making it even more constrained. And it would probably lead to table scan which may be much more expensive, depends on table size and array size. On 20M table it needs about 25000x more database resources than just querying all 5 rows with Contains. You should probably combine it with Contains filter to avoid the table scan, but that means three parameters per item...

Answer (score 0):

[Ctznkan525's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9086466/ctznkane525) answer gave me the idea to use ["Select with index"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to sort your array in the order or your priorities.

So you want all people with priority is first in the list or Priorities. 2nd are the people with priority that is mentioned 2nd in the list, 3rd are those with priority 3rd in the list etc.

Did you notice that I mentioned the index to identify the order? So if I add the index to your priorities list, I can order by this index.

This works if GetNearByPeopleList returns an IEnumerable.

```
var indexedPriorities = priorities.Select( (priority, index) => new
{
    Priority = priority,
    OrderIndex = index,
});
var result = GetNearbyPeopleList()
    .Where(...)                          // take only people you want
    .Join(indexedPriorities,             // join with indexedPriorities
    people => people.CurrentLocation,    // from each people take the CurrentLocation
    indexedPrio => indexedPrio.Priority, // from each indexedPriority take the priority
    (people, prio) => new                // when they match, make a new object
    {
        Index = prio.Index,              // containing the index of the matching priority
        People = people,                 // and the matching data
    })
    .OrderBy(item => item.Index)         // order by ascending index
    .Select(item => item.People);        // keep only the People
```

This code leaves out all people with CurrentLocation that are not in your Priority list. If you want them, you should Concat them where you want them, probably at the end.

Alas, [linq-to-entities does not support "select with index"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/supported-and-unsupported-linq-methods-linq-to-entities). You could try to first add the index, make your list AsQueryable and then do the join:

```
var indexedPriorities =  = priorities.Select( (priority, index) => new
{
    Priority = priority,
    OrderIndex = index,
})
.AsQueryable();

var result = GetNearbyPeopleList()
    .Where(...)       
    .Join(indexedPriorities, 
    people => people.CurrentLocation, CurrentLocation
    indexedPrio => indexedPrio.Priority, 
    ...
```

Alas this doesn't work, because you can only transfer simple types AsQueryable to be used in a join.

However, if the data is remote, and you really need this, you could transfer your priorities and indexes as a decimal:

```
  var indexedPriorities =  = priorities.Select( (x, i) => (decimal)x + (decimal)i/1000M)
      .AsQueryable();
```

The number before the decimal point is the priority, after the decimal point is the ordering index: (.001 comes before .002 etc

```
IQueryable<People> nearbyPeople = GetNearbyPeopleList()
   .Where(...);

var result = nearbyPeople.Join(indexedPriorities,
    people => people.CurrentLocation,
    prio => (int)Math.Floor(prio),
    (people, prio) => new
    {
        OrderIndex =(prio - Math.Truncate(prio),
        People = people,
    })
    .OrderBy(item => item.OrderIndex)
    .Select(item => item.People);
```

First I change the original priority list: { 866, 663, 855, 853, 854} into {866.000, 663.001, 855.002, 853.003, etc}. Assuming your priority list does not have 1000 elements.

Then I do a join with the Math.Floor of 866.000, 663.001 etc. When matching I keep the part after the decimal point as OrderIndex: .000, .001, .002 etc. (Not needed, but if desired: multiply by 1000)

After Ordering I get rid of the OrderIndex.

Comment: This fails for me with: System.NotSupportedException: An IQueryable that returns a self-referencing Constant expression is not supported.

Comment: I tried the method with the Math.Truncate, and it worked

Comment: Maybe it is just problem of the particular ORM. I would be curious what the generated sql looks like.